# Communication between Arduino Uno and Mega

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, hc-sr04

I am working on a project which uses a set of sensors (HC-SR04). These sensors use pins 2 to 13 of the Arduino Uno. Here you can find the board:

[image].

I also want to add an MP3 shield ([VS1053B](https://www.waveshare.com/music-shield.htm)) to it and it fills all the pins on Arduino. So I decided to add an Arduino Mega and add the sensors to it and use the Arduino Uno and MP3 shield. The problem is with connecting these two Arduinos. As I said the MP3 shield fills A4 and A5 pins too, so I can not use them to communicate with the Mega. What other options do I have?

Comment: the MP3 shield you linked doesn't use A4 and A5

Comment: and perhaps it can be used on Mega with changed pin mapping

Comment: @Juraj but it fills all pins when I put it on Arduino,

Comment: @Juraj actually I am thinking about using only MEGA, But I have no idea about changing pin mapping

Comment: the SPI pins should the shield connected over the ICSP header. it is on the same place on Uno and Mega. the helper pins are then connect to other gpio pin numbers on Mega.

Comment: all pins will be the same if the shield uses the ICSP header for SPI comunication

Comment: if you have the usual stackable shield headers on the shield, the you can connect to pins not used by the shield

Comment: @Juraj I noticed that the shield uses ICSP pins but It also uses A4 and A5 In its wiki it says:D11, D12 and D13 are the MISO, MOSI and SCLK buses of the SPI interface by default.

Comment: nothing about A4 and A5 in wiki. Yes, D11, D12 and D13 are SPI connected to D labeled pins and to ICSP header.

Answer (score 3):

You can multiplex the trigger line. With 3 pins you can address up to 8 sensors. If you multiplex the reply line as well (so you can abstract out the latency) you only need 2 additional pins for the actual trigger and reply.

Comment: So I do not need Adruino mega anymore? Can you give me a link about multiplexing the trigger line?sorry I am new to adruino

Answer (score 1):

Salam, you could somewhat multiplex the HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Sensor by using I2C(IIC) instruction on how to convert those into I2C and by using OctoSonar library can be [found here](https://hackaday.io/project/19950-hc-sr04-i2c-octopus-octosonar) so that only the SDA(pin16) and SCL(pin17) pins on your Arduino UNO will be used. 
https://hackaday.io/project/19950-hc-sr04-i2c-octopus-octosonar